# Disable onscreen keyboard Lubuntu at login

Tags: keyboard, login, screen, onscreen-keyboard

The keyboard is large and ugly.
How do I disable it in my upgraded 18.10 (from 18.04) at login screen?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
sudo gedit /etc/sddm.conf
```

Then in the General section add:

```
InputMethod=
```

Save and restart

Comment: Thanks, this works also on Lubuntu 20.04 (which was converted from a Kubuntu 20.04 installation). Note, if the `sddm.conf` file doesn't exist just create a new one.